# How to flatten the queried data

Tags: oracle

I am currently using the below query to pull the data which is being represented in 4 rows for the same sample record and would like to have it flattened into 1 ow per sample. Attaching the query results for information any help is much appreciated.

```
select s.name as CRF, a.name as Aliquot_Name, a.aliquot_type, au.u_step_yield as Step_Yield, au.u_step_concentration as Step_Concentration, au. u_pooled_plasma_volume as Pooled_Plasma_volume
from aliquot a 
join aliquot_user au on a.aliquot_id = au.aliquot_id 
join sample s on s.sample_id = a.SAMPLE_ID
where a.aliquot_type in ('DNA Extracted', 'Library', 'Target Enrichment', 'DNA Plasma')
order by s.name desc, a.aliquot_type, a.name, au.u_step_yield, au.u_step_concentration, au.u_pooled_plasma_volume;
```

```
CRF ALIQUOT_NAME    ALIQUOT_TYPE    STEP_YIELD  STEP_CONCENTRATION  POOLED_PLASMA_VOLUME
CRF007650   PE-0046758  DNA Plasma          10
CRF007650   LCNL-47275  Library 2,178   36  
CRF007650   HCNLS-47467 Target Enrichment   105 2   
CRF007649   1146667362  DNA Extracted   451 6   
CRF007649   PE-0046774  DNA Plasma          10
CRF007649   LCNL-47291  Library 3,543   59  
CRF007649   HCNLS-47483 Target Enrichment   132 2   
CRF007648   1146668498  DNA Extracted   166 2   
CRF007648   PE-0046755  DNA Plasma          9
CRF007648   LCNL-47272  Library 3,881   65  
CRF007648   HCNLS-47463 Target Enrichment   381 6   
CRF007647   1146635220  DNA Extracted   29  0   
CRF007647   PE-0046764  DNA Plasma          8
CRF007647   LCNL-47281  Library 1,274   21  
CRF007647   HCNLS-47473 Target Enrichment   57  1   
CRF007646   1146736347  DNA Extracted   67  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to more specific. 
There's no tables' info. which is pk and which is not.
Only I can say now is that you have to join same table if you want to flatten rows.
If you want to get answer with query, you have to write your tables' info and others can help people answer your question.

Comment: There are 3 tables being used Aliquot, Aliquot_User and Sample. the primary key on the Aliquot and Aliquot_USER table is Aliquot ID and on the sample table is SAMPLE_ID. Aliquot and Aliquot_User are the children on the system for a given system and they do have Sample ID information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your data you have 4 entrys in your table a with different a.aliquot_type ('DNA Extracted', 'Library', 'Target Enrichment', 'DNA Plasma'). And you want to give 4 columns with the corresponding Aliquot_Name (one for 'DNA Extracted' etc.).

You could use 4 columns with a subselect where you read the corresponding data from aliquot and therefore you have to quit the join

```
a.aliquot_id = au.aliquot_id
```

For example:

```
select s.name as CRF, (select a.aliquot_type from aliquot where a.aliquot_type = 'DNA Extracted' and ....) col1,  (select a.aliquot_type from aliquot where a.aliquot_type = 'Library' and ....) col2, ...
```